# Add block before content in magento page

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout

I need to add a block right after the breadcrumbs in one of my pages, `my-page`

I tried creating a block called `my-block` in the admin, and adding `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my-block') ?>` in `frontend/theme/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml` and it doesn't show the contents of the block `my-block`.

I also added

```
<page-name>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="my-block" as="my-block" before="content" after="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/my-block.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</page-name>
```

In the local.xml file, but I'm not sure if it was really necessary.

Am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cms blocks have to be called differently to echo out their contents.

To render the block on all pages below breadcrumbs.phtml:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml

Add this after breadcrumbs:

> In Layout.xml

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_name">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my-block</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Then you'll have to echo it out in 3columns.phtml:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my-block') ?>
```

Might be easier to do it on a per-page basis.

Turn on template hints, find a block you want to append your cms content to and place the following in it:

> In template file:

```
 // Insert the block into the page.
$sBlockId = 'my-block';
$oBlock = Mage::getModel( 'cms/block' );
$oBlock->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() );
$oBlock->load( $sBlockId, 'identifier' );
$oCmsHelper = Mage::helper( 'cms' );
$oProcessor = $oCmsHelper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$sHtml = $oProcessor->filter( $oBlock->getContent() );
echo $sHtml;
```

> OR:

```
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock( 'cms/block' )->setBlockId( 'my-block' )->toHtml();
```

Ideally you likely want to create a template that is then attached via layout.xml and inside that template you echo our your cms block.

> **Creating a template that renders your cms block wherever you desire:**
>
> app\etc\modules\Spirit_Cms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Spirit_Cms>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Spirit_Cms>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Spirit\Cms\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Spirit_Cms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Spirit_Cms>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <spirit_cms>
                    <file>custom.xml</file>
                </spirit_cms>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom" template="custom.phtml" output="toHtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\custom.phtml

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock( 'cms/block' )->setBlockId( 'custom' )->toHtml(); ?>
```

More flexibility/less clutter adding content in a specified location.

Comment: One sec man was answering a long question.. Will be editing an example shortly.

Comment: I added a full method for adding cms blocks up above